# Squirrelmail issue: ERROR: Could not complete request. Query: SELECT “INBOX”

Tags: email, ubuntu, server, lamp

I have website server hosted on digitalocean with Ubuntu 16.04, LAMP. So, when I need to have my own domain name email address, I followed this tutorial to create one. After going through the tutorial I was able to send a mail but could not receive because the squirrel browser interface says:

```
enter code here
ERROR: Could not complete request.
Query: SELECT "INBOX"
Reason Given: [SERVERBUG] Internal error occurred. Refer to server log for more information. [2018-08-22 03:58:59] (0.000 + 0.000 secs).


This is the error log
---------------------

Aug 22 03:44:58 haemocaregate dovecot: imap(daniolayinka): Error: open(/var/mail/daniolayinka) failed: Permission denied (euid=1003(daniolayinka) egi$
Aug 22 03:44:58 haemocaregate dovecot: imap(daniolayinka): Error: Failed to autocreate mailbox INBOX: Internal error occurred. Refer to server log fo$
Aug 22 03:44:59 haemocaregate dovecot: imap(daniolayinka): Error: open(/var/mail/daniolayinka) failed: Permission denied (euid=1003(daniolayinka) egi$
Aug 22 03:44:59 haemocaregate dovecot: imap(daniolayinka): Error: Failed to autocreate mailbox INBOX: Internal error occurred. Refer to server log fo$
Aug 22 03:49:40 haemocaregate dovecot: imap(daniolayinka): Error: open(/var/mail/daniolayinka) failed: Permission denied (euid=1003(daniolayinka) egi$
Aug 22 03:49:40 haemocaregate dovecot: imap(daniolayinka): Error: Failed to autocreate mailbox INBOX: Internal error occurred. Refer to server log fo$
Aug 22 03:49:40 haemocaregate dovecot: imap(daniolayinka): Error: open(/var/mail/daniolayinka) failed: Permission denied (euid=1003(daniolayinka) egi$
Aug 22 03:49:40 haemocaregate dovecot: imap(daniolayinka): Error: Failed to autocreate mailbox INBOX: Internal error occurred. Refer to server log fo$
Aug 22 03:58:03 haemocaregate dovecot: imap(daniolayinka): Error: open(/var/mail/daniolayinka) failed: Permission denied (euid=1003(daniolayinka) egi$
Aug 22 03:58:03 haemocaregate dovecot: imap(daniolayinka): Error: Failed to autocreate mailbox INBOX: Internal error occurred. Refer to server log fo$
Aug 22 03:58:03 haemocaregate dovecot: imap(daniolayinka): Error: open(/var/mail/daniolayinka) failed: Permission denied (euid=1003(daniolayinka) egi$
Aug 22 03:58:03 haemocaregate dovecot: imap(daniolayinka): Error: Failed to autocreate mailbox INBOX: Internal error occurred. Refer to server log fo$
Aug 22 03:58:10 haemocaregate dovecot: imap(daniolayinka): Error: open(/var/mail/daniolayinka) failed: Permission denied (euid=1003(daniolayinka) egi$
Aug 22 03:58:10 haemocaregate dovecot: imap(daniolayinka): Error: Failed to autocreate mailbox INBOX: Internal error occurred. Refer to server log fo$
Aug 22 03:58:59 haemocaregate dovecot: imap(daniolayinka): Error: open(/var/mail/daniolayinka) failed: Permission denied (euid=1003(daniolayinka) egi$
Aug 22 03:58:59 haemocaregate dovecot: imap(daniolayinka): Error: Failed to autocreate mailbox INBOX: Internal error occurred. Refer to server log fo$
Aug 22 03:58:59 haemocaregate dovecot: imap(daniolayinka): Error: open(/var/mail/daniolayinka) failed: Permission denied (euid=1003(daniolayinka) egi$
Aug 22 03:58:59 haemocaregate dovecot: imap(daniolayinka): Error: Failed to autocreate mailbox INBOX: Internal error occurred. Refer to server log fo$
```

Answer (score 0):

From your logs, it is obvious that this is a permission issue. dovecot is trying to open a path `/var/mail/daniolayinka` which it can't access for one of two reasons:

1. The path exists but devcot cannot open it because of permission issues
2. The path does not exist and devcot does not have permission to create it

Solution:

1. If the path does not exist, create it and retry.
2. If the path does exist, then make sure you've set the right permissions. E.g you may run the following command. `chmod -R 755 /var/mail/daniolayinka`

Comment: Thanks. <br> I tried the code at first, and it says the directory does not exist. So I run a mkdir /var/mail/daniolayinka, <br> then ran this code chmod -R 755 /var/mail/daniolayinka <br> Yet the mail didn't deliver.

Comment: This is the new error message: {Aug 31 11:40:55 haemocaregate dovecot: imap(daniolayinka): Error: Opening INBOX failed: Mailbox isn't selectable
Aug 31 11:40:56 haemocaregate dovecot: imap(daniolayinka): Error: Opening}